# Updating multiple documents using array of object

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am using express.js server. I am trying to update existing documents in mongodb collection **using mongoose** with array of objects (each object has `_id` property and its value corresponds to each document `_id`.)

One approach is loop through array and execute `findByIdAndUpdate()`

```
for(var i=0; i < expenseListToEdit.length; i++) {    
    var expense = expenseListToEdit[i];

    Expense.findByIdAndUpdate(expense._id, expense, function(err, model) {
        if (err) {    
            console.log('Error occurred while editing expense');
        }

        console.log('model: ' + util.inspect(model));
    });
}
```

But this way I will have to handle asynchronous scenario and will have to check when db query for all iteration is finished then only send response back to client from server.

Is there any alternate approach within mongoose to edit/modify array of object in one go and then call the callback?

Note*- Each array object has `_id` present which is matched with document `_id` value.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's quite possible. You could take advantage of using a bulk write API for handling the async operations and thus better performance, especially dealing with large datasets. For Mongoose versions `>=4.3.0` which support `MongoDB Server 3.2.x`, 
you can use **[`bulkWrite()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/#db.collection.bulkWrite)** for updates. The following example shows how you can go about this:

```
var bulkUpdateCallback = function(err, r){
    console.log(r.matchedCount);
    console.log(r.modifiedCount);
}
// Initialise the bulk operations array
var bulkOps = expenseListToEdit.map(function (expense) { 
    return { 
        "updateOne": { 
            "filter": { "_id": expense._id } ,              
            "update": { "$set": expense } 
        }         
    }    
});

// Get the underlying collection via the native node.js driver collection object
Expense.collection.bulkWrite(bulkOps, { "ordered": true, w: 1 }, bulkUpdateCallback);
```

For Mongoose versions `~3.8.8, ~3.8.22, 4.x` which support MongoDB Server `>=2.6.x`, you could use **[`Bulk API`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/Bulk/)** as follows

```
var bulk = Expense.collection.initializeOrderedBulkOp(),
    counter = 0;

expenseListToEdit.forEach(function(expense) {
    bulk.find({ "_id": expense._id })
        .updateOne({ "$set": expense });

    counter++;
    if (counter % 500 == 0) {
        bulk.execute(function(err, r) {
           // do something with the result
           bulk = Expense.collection.initializeOrderedBulkOp();
           counter = 0;
        });
    }
});

// Catch any docs in the queue under or over the 500's
if (counter > 0) {
    bulk.execute(function(err, result) {
       // do something with the result here
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to change the `for` statement by `async.each` http://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#each :

Warning : The each launch all elements in parallel.

```
async.each(expenseListToEdit, function (expense, done) {
    Expense.findByIdAndUpdate(expense._id, expense, function(err, model) {
        if (err) {    
           console.log('Error occurred while editing expense');
           done(err); // if an error occured, all each is stoped
           return;
        }

        console.log('model: ' + util.inspect(model));
        done();
    });
}, function (err) {
    // final callback launched after all findByIdAndUpdate calls.
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (let i of expenseListToEdit) {
    Expense.findByIdAndUpdate(i._id, {})
    .exec()
    .then(function updated(expense) {
        if (expense) {
            //DO SMTH
        }
        }).then(null, function(err) {
            console.error(err)
            throw err;
        })
}
```

Comment: please try to add some explanation as to how this code works and why, maybe with links to documentation